# Vimdiff does not read modeline

Tags: vimdiff, modeline

I have a modeline in a file

```
# vim: set filetype=sshconfig :
```

This sets `filetype` correctly in vim, but when opening the file in vimdiff, the filetype is set to `conf`. How can I tell vimdiff to read the modeline?

I'm using Vim 7.4.258 from MacPorts on Mac OS X.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. With two files, one containing your modeline, `vimdiff -N -u NONE file1 file2` always sets the `'filetype'` correctly. I'm using Vim 7.4.729 on Fedora.

Comment: I can't reproduce with `vimdiff` either, 7.4.692 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tracked it down**
I had installed [vim-scripts/diffchar](https://github.com/vim-scripts/diffchar.vim) using Vundle, but it wasn't working so I commented it out and forgot about it. Running `:PluginClean` did the trick.

Comment: I use `diffchar`, and it didn't cause any problems reading from the modeline. O.o But then again, the plugin does work for me.